# copy styles from office 2010 word document to another

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

Can anyone tell me how to copy styles from one word (2010) document to another? Seemed like a very obvious thing but is apparantly not.

Also, is there a command, script that I can run against a word 2010 document (source) which has the styles that I want to copy to a new word 2010 document (destination) that does not have those styles. I want to do this copy from one source document to a number of destination documents in one step.

Comment: For Word 2003: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/copy-styles-to-another-document-or-template-HP005189264.aspx

Answer (score 29):

I've found that the easiest way to do this within Word is to open the new document (that you want to import the style to).

To do this, first open the **Styles Window** (Alt+Ctrl+Shift+S), and click on **Manage Styles**.
At the bottom of the Manage Styles window is **Import/Export...**.
You can then choose another file by closing your normal.dotm file, and using **Open File** to select file with style(s), then copying the required styles across.

Works for 2013, 2010, 2007.
In 2007 the **Manage Styles** is a small icon in the **Styles Window**

In pictures:

[image: Show styles]

[image: Manage styles]

[image: Import Export]

[image: Close Normal.dot]

[image: Open File]

Comment: This also works for Word 2013.

Comment: Thanks. I believe it also worked for 2007, but can't prove it at the moment.

Comment: This also works for **Microsoft Office 365**.

Comment: Is there a way to automate this from a single "template" to many documents?

Answer (score 2):

The method is as follows:

1. Developer tab.
2. Click Document Template.
3. Click Attach to navigate to the target document or template.
4. Once back in the Templates and Add-ins dialog, click to enable 
   Automatically update document styles.
5. Click OK.

Note: if the Developer tab is missing, choose Office button - Word Options - 
Popular tab, and click to enable "Show Developer tab in the ribbon".

Source: http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=104074

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to save the style into another dotx it seems, by following your suggestion. Ideally, I would want to transfer the style directly to the document I am working on rather than work onthe newly created dotx.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy styles from one Word 2010 document to another very easily.

1. Open the document that you want to copy the styles to.
2. Using the *Developer* tab, click on *Add-Ins* button.
3. Click on the *Organizer* button at the bottom left.
4. On the right click on *Close File*.
5. It will then change to *Open File*. Click on that and go out and find where the file is located that you want to copy the styles from and click on it.
6. When it comes in, it will have the Styles in it that you can choose from.
7. Select either each one you want or a bunch of them and click on the *Copy* button, but you must click it 3 times in order for it to work properly (I forget why just now but that is how it works. It is something to do with Parent->Child->Grandfather, but I forget just now).
8. Once done, stay where you are and click on the *Close* button and click on the other *Close* button too and that is it. The styles you want will now be in your document.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is another simple method to do this like I always did.
If your Styles is in Document A, open Document A and ‘**save as**’ to another name such as Document B. Your Styles now will be available in Document B. Delete ‘old content’ in Document B and copy your new manuscript into Document B and apply the Styles to your text. I think that should be ok. :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the question and if you are copying just a few styles, the easiest is just to copy any text with the style you want and pasting it on the target document. The style will also be copied and will stay there even if you delete the text (don't undo instead of delete!).

Answer (score 0):

The method is as follows:

- Developer tab.
- Click Document Template.
- Click Attach to navigate to the target document or template.
- Once back in the Templates and Add-ins dialog, click to enable Automatically update document styles.
- Click OK.

This one worked for me.